# PHP остаток от деления

Tags: php

Добрый вечер! Работаю на php, подскажите, есть код:

```
<?php
echo 2267127296 % 10000;
?>
```

Скажите, почему выдает 0? Должно быть 7296! Что не так?

Comment: Уверены? У меня выдаёт 7296.

Comment: Что за php у вас там? [4.3-7.2](https://3v4l.org/SXp3J)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос версию php и, что важнее, разрядность ОС.

Comment: ОС: windows 7, php 5.6.27. Скорее всего нужно сменить версию php. Проверил на другой версии, всё ок. Решилась проблема)

Comment: Дело не в версии было, а каких-то других причинах, потому что так везде должно вывести